# WPF finding resource and memory leaks

Tags: wpf, memory, resources, memory-leaks

Does anyone have some suggestions for issolating resource and/or memory leaks in a WPF application?

I have verified that there does appears to be some significant leaks in our application through the monitoring of heap sizes in Task Manager while using the application.  I did download the evaluation of the Memory Profiler tool, played with it for an hour or so and moved on.  Now my evaluation period has expired.  While using it many issues were reported, but I had not invested the time to wade through all of the verbose report.

What is the best tool for this?  Should I invest the time and money on Memory Profiler or go with something else.  I used to use BoundsChecker in C++ and it was great, slowed down the application a lot but pinpointed right where you had an issue.

I would like a tool to identify the source of our leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any .net memory profiling tool would do. For WPF specific memory profiling we used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx.

But we could also do better memory profiling of our WPF application using `WinDbg` .... even `SOS` helps. You just need to have a way to understand its commands.

Comment: Do you have any experience with RedGate?  I'm thinking our memory leaks may not be directly related to WPF, but to general .NET development.